# capitalize list_display header for a property in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a property that is an acronym, say, `FOO`, that I want to display in the admin as `FOO`. It displays as `Foo`. Can I make it display as `FOO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - You can override the admin template, and apply the `{{..|upper}}` filter.

Overriding admin templates can be found [here](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/01/20/overriding-django-admin-templates-for-fun-and-profit/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)

Another way would be:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_foo','somethingelse')

    def upper_case_foo(self, obj):
        return ("%s"%(obj.foo)).upper()
    upper_case_foo.short_description = 'FOO'
```

documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: I somehow totally missed that in the documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but I guess you can use `short_description` for this:

```
def foo(self):
  # your code here

foo.short_description = 'FOO'
```

Comment: I think short_descriptions are only for the list display headers. documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Isn't that what the OP is asking?

Comment: Exactly what I was asking. Thanks.

Comment: Python 2.7 says you can't set something on a property that way, just so you know.